# Error when trying to create non-clustered index in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, non-clustered-index

I am trying to create a non-clustered index in my SQL Server table.

Upon right-clicking on the table's index folder I am getting the message:

> To accomplish this action set property PartitionScheme

What is `PartictionScheme` and how am I supposed to set it?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/107497/5203?

Comment: Partition scheme is a scheme in the current database that maps the partitions of a partitioned table or index to filegroups. Check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/modify-a-partition-scheme?view=sql-server-2017 and for Adding Indexes To a Partitioned table: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/76795/adding-indexes-to-a-partitioned-table-in-sql-server-2012